# Save oauth/token body into Java object

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jackson

After I successfully run the request to *http://IP:port/oauth/ token* to get the authorization token from oauth using spring framework, the response body looks something like this:

```
{
     access_token = jsjxjdnjf .... some_acces_token,
     token_type: bearer,
     (....) more fields
}
```

The client to acces this endpoint is a simple Java app using org.springframework.web.client.RestTeplate
My question is:
Is there a predefined class that allows me to encapsulate(map) that information and access it through getters?
Or I have to implement it myself, which would look like this:

```
public class OauthTokeWrapper {
private String access_token;
(...)//getters,constructors...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to read access tokens in the OAuth Client, which should just treat the token as an opaque string to be sent to APIs. Access tokens are not always JWT format and reading tokens in the client could lead to future problems.

Instead it is typical to work with the API claims in a back end API. One option for doing this is via the [Nimbus libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk). Here is some [example API code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java) of mine in case useful.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm still checking the details but it's exactly what I was looking for. I just have a question, is there any implementation compatible with jdk1.8

Comment: The above libs will work fine in a Java 8 project - it is just my sample that uses a later version